# Android 12 TinkerBoard AOSP build triggering ethernet disconnection signal

Tags: android, android-source

We are currently in the process of evaluating the option to migrate to the new TinkerBoard for our project. During our testing, we have encountered an issue related to Ethernet connectivity that we would appreciate your assistance with. Using android 12 aosp build.

Specifically, we have observed that when we connect the TinkerBoard to our custom switch using a static IP address, the board does not establish a connection automatically. However, when we connect the TinkerBoard directly to a laptop's Ethernet port, the adb reboot functionality works reliably every time.

Our suspicion is that there might be a compatibility issue between this particular TinkerBoard and our custom switch, causing the system to erroneously consider itself disconnected instead of connected after a power cycle. We are eager to find a workaround or solution to this intermittent disconnection problem.

Could you kindly provide us with any insights or recommendations on how to address this issue? We are open to adjusting our configuration or considering alternative approaches to ensure stable Ethernet connectivity when using the TinkerBoard with our custom switch.

Not working:

[image]

Working:

[image]

Added new dedicated Java system service to monitor the ethernet connection, and triggerring reconnection. This also not helping this hardware problem.

```
private BroadcastReceiver networkReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
                    // Ethernet is connected
                    Log.i(TAG, "Ethernet network is connected.");
                } else {
                    // Ethernet is disconnected, initiate reconnection
                    Log.e(TAG, "Ethernet is disconnected. Initiating reconnection.");
                    reconnectEthernet();
                }
            }
        }
    };

NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET);
        builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
```

```
    connectivityManager.requestNetwork(builder.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
        // The Ethernet network is now reconnected.
        Log.i(TAG, "Ethernet network is reconnected.");
        retryCount = 0;
    }
```